# Insert google adsense code after a specific paragraph in php

Tags: php

I am trying from quite some time to insert javascript code (adsense) into a specific post (a question) in a php-driven question and answer type of website, with no luck so far. I am trying to override the required function that displays the post with the following code:

```
    public function q_view_content($q_view) {

    qa_html_theme_base::q_view_content($q_view);

    if(isset($q_view['raw']['postid'])) {
        if($q_view['raw']['postid'] == '203') {

            $content_block = explode('<p>',$q_view);
            if(!empty($content_block[2]))
            {   $content_block[2] .= '<div align="center">
                My awesome code here</div>';
            }
            for($i=1;$i<count($content_block);$i++)
            {   $content_block[$i] = '<p>'.$content_block[$i];
            }
            $q_view = implode('',$content_block);

            $this->output($q_view);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, instead of displaying the code on the webpage, I got the following errors: 
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given on line 37;
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed on line 45

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you review the manual, and as the error says, `explode()` [requires two values that are strings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). `$q_view` is an array, not a string, therefore you can not split it with a string function.

This would be valid:

```
$array = explode('0',$q_view['raw']['postid']);
print_r($array);
```

And would give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

Therefore, you can not do this:

```
$content_block = explode('<p>',$q_view);
```

because `$q_view` is not a string, it's an array.

The other issue is related to the the `explode()` since it could not split the array, therefore `$content_block` is not an array and so `implode()` fails.